# Adding lists as elements to make a list of list

Tags: list, ocaml

For my assignment, I need to return a list of lists given a tree. [image]
[image]

For example, given this tree, we return the paths of the leaves, 0 being going to the left and 1 being going to the right. At the current moment, I believe my function makes sense; however, I have no idea how to make the lists into a list of lists. I believe an operation needs to be put where the question mark is; however I've looked online and I could not find anything. Is there an operation for this? Or do I have to create my own helper function? Thank you.

```
let rec dTree_path t = 
   match t with 
   | Leaf(x) -> []
   | Node(x, lt, rt) -> [ 0 :: (dTree_path lt) ] ?? [1 :: (dTree_path rt)];;
```

I

Comment: After looking at my function again, it wouldn't work exactly since I recursively call 0 and 1 even if the lt or  rt is empty, so if there is any advice on how to fix that as well, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When doing exercices where function types are well specified, it can be useful to write the specification explicitely in order to make the typechecker report issues as soon as possible. In this case, adding a type annotation yields a compiler error on `0::dTree_path lt`

```
let rec dTree_path: 'any t -> int list list = fun x ->
  match x with 
  | Leaf(x) -> []
  | Node(x, lt, rt) -> [ 0 :: (dTree_path lt) ] …;;
```

> Error: This expression has type int list list
>          but an expression was expected of type int list
>          Type int list is not compatible with type int

And indeed, the current issue with your function is that `0 :: (dTree_path lt)` does not make sense with respect to your specification: `dTree_path` is a list of lists of ints (i.e. a list of paths), but you are appending an int element to this list.

Hint: What you want to do is to append `0` to each path of the list of path returned by `dTree_path`.

Comment: Hmm I understand whay you mean as dTree_path returns a list of lists; however, I'm confused what you mean in your hint. How would I create each path in the first place, and what would appending zero to each path do?

Comment: `dTree_path t` returns a list of paths starting from the root of tree `t`. Then, you should ask yourself two questions: First, if you have a path of the left subtree of `Node(_, left_subtree, _)` how do you transform this path into a path of the whole tree? Second, if you have a list of elements, how do you apply the same transformation to each element?